# 404 on auth0 callback when trying to login on app deployed on heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, callback, auth0

I have a PERN stack app using auth0 for login that is working fine on localhost but when deployed to heroku after I click to sign in I get a 404 on the callback.

The URL is exactly the same except for appname instead of localhost on all routes, i have also the env variables and callback and logout urls setup in auth0 correctly.

Is there anyone who has run into this and can help me solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

check your port. I *thought* my port was 3000 (I'm using Next.js on Heroku with Auth0), but it actually isn't running on 3000, but whatever Heroku decides. I changed my auth0 `Allowed Callback URLs` and all is working!